# ListBox with syle and Datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have style for ListBox and ListBoxItem

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBackground}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,0,5,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="35"
                                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ItemsControl Focusable="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                            <ContentPresenter Tag="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GlassFX}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I am adding a new ListBox on the MainWindow:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableClient}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListBoxItem Tag="{Binding Path=ID}" Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

But my binding does not work...

If change style

```
<ContentPresenter Tag="{Binding Path=Tag.ID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Content="{Binding Path=Content.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

All work. But I need a universal style for many listbox.
How can I do that?

Comment: then why not just create a `UserControl` ?

Comment: I need a unified style so that it can be used in other projects.

Comment: U can use a UserControl in any project u want

Comment: Yes, but it does not suit me :)

Comment: Hmm....good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VisualStudio create a new `Resource Dictionary` in your solution, then copy your style into it like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        -Your style code here-
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then, either in your Window/Usercontrol resources or preferably your App.xaml file, load your Resource Dictionary like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="whatever you named the file.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now your custom style should override the style for all listboxes in your solution. If you want to use your style in another solution, simply put the xaml file you created into your solution and load it like above.